python pyproject.toml - arch dependency solved on install
In pyproject.toml we have a optional-dependencies for a windows package:
[project.optional-dependencies]
windows = [
    "pywinpty>=2.0.14"
]

To install:
# on windows
pip install .[windows]
# on linux/mac we use the enclosed pty
pip install .

Is it possible so pip install . does this check automatic?
Or uv pip install . (pywinpty is a rust package)

You can use PEP 496 – Environment Markers and PEP 508 – Dependency specification for Python Software Packages; they're usable in setup.py, setup.cfg, pyproject.toml, requirements.txt. In particular in pyproject.toml:
[project]
dependencies = [
    "pywinpty>=2.0.14; sys_platform == 'win32'"
]


I got hanged up in optional-dependencies, when you know where to look, it is documented here: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/#dependencies-and-requirements
